# EACCES: permission denied, open '/usr/src/app/vite.config.ts.timestamp-1705061932318-ddf27d1489a34.mjs'

Tags: node.js, docker, vite

I'm trying to run my vite project in a docker container, but I get the following error once the container runs:

```
`2024-01-12 12:18:50 
2024-01-12 12:18:50 > dmsosa@0.0.0 dev
2024-01-12 12:18:50 > vite
2024-01-12 12:18:50 
2024-01-12 12:18:52 failed to load config from /usr/src/app/vite.config.ts
2024-01-12 12:18:52 error when starting dev server:
2024-01-12 12:18:52 Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/usr/src/app/vite.config.ts.timestamp-1705061932318-ddf27d1489a34.mjs'`
```

What can be the reason for this?, I tried doing changes in my Dockerfile, I'm not sure if the dependencies are being installed correctly from my host to the image (and then into the container)

Here is my dockerfile:

```
ARG NODE_VERSION=20.6.1

FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}-alpine

# Use production node environment by default.
ENV NODE_ENV dev
ENV PORT 5173

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.npm \
    npm install -g npm@10.3.0

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm i

# Run the application as a non-root user.
USER node

# Copy the rest of the source files into the image.
COPY . .

# Expose the port that the application listens on.
EXPOSE ${PORT}

# Run the application.
CMD cd /usr/src/app && npm run dev
```

Here it is the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "dmsosa",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.11.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.12.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.20.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.37",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.15",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.10.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.10.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint": "^8.53.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.4",
    "sass": "^1.69.5",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "vite": "^5.0.0"
  }
}
```

vite.config.ts if useful:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react({
    include: "**/*.tsx",
  })]
})
```

I tried updating the npm to the last version using `npm install -g npm@10.3.0`, but it did not worked
Also, tried to create mount binds between my host and the image for package.json and package-lock.json files, but nothing changed.

What can be a solution for it?

Comment: Version of `vite`?  (seeing this possible related fix: fix: [avoid crash because of no access permission](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/blob/main/packages/vite/CHANGELOG.md#:~:text=fix%3A%20avoid%20crash%20because%20of%20no%20access%20permission%20(%2312552))

Comment: thanks for your answer! I will let the solutions down below.

The issue was in my dockerfile, the container have to run `npm install` after you copy the node_modules folder from the image.

By the way, the vite version is 5.0.7

Answer (score -1):

The issue was in my dockerfile, the `npm install` commands was executed before copying the folder node_modules to the container, so when the container got created it have no access to that folder.

Solution is that it is the container which install the dependencies, so it has all the permissions required to execute the files.

1. Copy node_modules to the container
2. Run `npm install`

Updated docker file:

```
ARG NODE_VERSION=20.6.1

FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}-alpine

# Use production node environment by default.
ENV NODE_ENV dev
ENV PORT 5173

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./package.json ./package-lock.json ./

RUN npm i

# Copy the rest of the source files into the image.
COPY . .

# Expose the port that the application listens on.
EXPOSE ${PORT}

# Run the application.
CMD npm run dev
```

then run `docker run --my-container -d -p 5173:5173  [image_name]` and it works

Comment: The reason that it works is that you removed the line `USER node` from Dockerfile

Comment: Oh, take it into account, thanks!